# Unexplained stretching of path automata using tikz in Latex

Tags: pdf, automata, tikz-pgf

I'm writing a maths report in Latex which requires drawing Free State Automata. Up until this point in the document, using the `tikz` package was great, but it is being inexplicably weird. I am trying to copy a few iterations of the same automata, like so:

```
\item{Show the computation of your deterministic automaton for the input tape $abb$.


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, every state/.style={align=center,minimum size=1.5cm,text width=1cm}]
  \node     [initial, state]    (q0)                    {$q_0$};
  \node     [state]             (q0q1) [right of=q0]    {$\{q_0,q_1\}$};
  \node     [state,accepting]   (q1q2) [right of=q1]    {$\{q_1,q_2\}$};
  \node     [state]             (q1) [right of=q1q2]    {$q_1$};

  \path[->]
        (q0)    edge                node {a} (q0q1)
        (q0q1)  edge [bend left]    node {a} (q0)
        (q0q1)  edge                node {b} (q1q2)
        (q1q2)  edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1)
        (q1)    edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1q2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, every state/.style={align=center,minimum size=1.5cm,text width=1cm}]
  \node     [initial, state]    (q0)                    {$q_0$};
  \node     [state]             (q0q1) [right of=q0]    {$\{q_0,q_1\}$};
  \node     [state,accepting]   (q1q2) [right of=q1]    {$\{q_1,q_2\}$};
  \node     [state]             (q1) [right of=q1q2]    {$q_1$};

  \path[->]
        (q0)    edge                node {a} (q0q1)
        (q0q1)  edge [bend left]    node {a} (q0)
        (q0q1)  edge                node {b} (q1q2)
        (q1q2)  edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1)
        (q1)    edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This results in this happening:

[image: Result of latex code]

i.e. the path from `(q0q1)` to `(q1q2)` stretches on each iteration. The automata appears absolutely fine in the previous part of the question, using the exact same code, but each iteration causes more and more stretching.
It has not done this for a previous automata that I repeated several times.

Can anybody spot anything?

Thanks

Comment: I get some tikz related errors, could you provide a minimal document?

Comment: Your code contain errors: node names aren't correct order, You use obsolete syntax for positioning: `right of= q1` instead of `right=of q1` and maybe more. Image in your link wasn't generated by code in your question! Please, provide minimal workable example.

Answer (score 1):

Partly rewritten your code -- I change the order of appearance of states and their names, correct syntax of state nodes positioning -- gives expected result:

[image]

From above pictures follows that in it is not any strange stretching. For them I use the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, every state/.style={align=center,minimum size=1.5cm,text width=1cm}]
  \node     [initial, state]    (q0)                    {$q_0$};
  \node     [state]             (q0q1) [right=of q0]    {$\{q_0,q_1\}$};
  \node     [state,accepting]   (q1q2) [right=of q0q1]    {$\{q_1,q_2\}$};
  \node     [state]             (q1)   [right=of q1q2]  {$q_1$};

  \path[->]
        (q0)    edge                node {a} (q0q1)
        (q0q1)  edge [bend left]    node {a} (q0)
        (q0q1)  edge                node {b} (q1q2)
        (q1q2)  edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1)
        (q1)    edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1q2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, every state/.style={align=center,minimum size=1.5cm,text width=1cm}]
  \node     [initial, state]    (q0)                    {$q_0$};
  \node     [state]             (q0q1) [right=of q0]    {$\{q_0,q_1\}$};
  \node     [state,accepting]   (q1q2) [right=of q0q1]  {$\{q_1,q_2\}$};
  \node     [state]             (q1)   [right=of q1q2]  {$q_1$};

  \path[->]
        (q0)    edge                node {a} (q0q1)
        (q0q1)  edge [bend left]    node {a} (q0)
        (q0q1)  edge                node {b} (q1q2)
        (q1q2)  edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1)
        (q1)    edge [bend left]    node {b} (q1q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For `documentclass` I use standalone package with necessary TikZ libraries. As I see from your snipped of code, it is unusual included in some list. Normal it should follow item:

```
\item  Show the computation of your deterministic automaton for the input tape $abb$.

\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}

\item ...
```